# how to generate scatter plots between outcome variable and one of independent variable

Tags: regression

plot(x, y) can generate scatter plots for simple regression results y=a +bx; then how to generate scatter plots between outcome variable and one of independent variable for regression results Y=A+bX1 + cX2 +dX3?  can we run y=a1 +cX2 +dX3 to get residuals, and then plot residuals ~ X1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Syntax doesn't change. Just remember that if you are working with R, syntax should be

```
plot(model$residuals, variable)
```

Where "model" is your linear model

By the way, if you want to store residuals in your dataset, then you should type:

```
db$errors <- model$residual
```

Where "db" is your dataset